AsyncApi to document Java classes
I'm trying to use jasyncapi to document a Java async (message driven) api, but I can't find any code or examples. Has anyone used this tool, and if so, can they point me to some documentation and sample code?

Author in thread)
Can you describe your scenario?
Looks like you are trying to generate AsyncAPI from application, if so, you can checkout this projects:

Spring - https://www.springwolf.dev
Quarkus - https://quarkus.io/extensions/io.quarkiverse.asyncapi/quarkus-asyncapi

My library is for low-level working with our specification, like creation of tools on Java/Kotlin

That is exactly what I would like to do - generate AsyncAPI from my application. I'll have a look at the projects you mention: thank you.
